# Kafka Connect MySQL to ES

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Lets say I want to move data from 3 mysql tables to 1 ES index using Kafka connectors.

This 3 tables are the result of database normalization, in ES there is no need to have 3 indices for this, ideally I would have one index and each document on that index would have properties. For example in MySQL I have 3 tables Person, Cars, Houses
So a Person can have many cars and many houses. In ES I would like to have a document like this:

```
{
    "name": "Peter",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [{
        "color": "red"
    }],
    "houses": [{
        "address": "street 1"
    }]
}
```

Would it be better to:

1. Use one `JdbcSourceConnector` using a query that would join the 3 tables and write that to a topic, and then use a `ElasticsearchSinkConnector` to sync that stream to an ES index.
2. Create 3 `JdbcSourceConnector` one for each table, join streams/tables in KSQL to generate one stream with data from the 3 MySQL tables and then one `ElasticsearchSinkConnector` to sync that stream to an ES index.

Note: I already tried option **2** but for some reason I see the index in ES but no documents.